# Delete everything after the first white space in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to use the update function to delete everything after the first white blank space.  i have tied this but not working for me so far...
here is my code:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyField= LEFT(MyField, CHARINDEX('', MyField) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX('', MyField) > 0
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? And an empty string `''` is not the same thing as a space `' '`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have no space in between those single quotes so it is not matching on anything:

```
UPDATE MyTable                        
SET MyField= LEFT(MyField, CHARINDEX(' ', MyField) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', MyField) > 0;    ^-- this should be a space
                 ^-- this should be a space
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c22b/2).

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL:

```
update MyTable set MyField = substring(MyField for (position(' ' in MyField) - 1))
where MyField  like '% %';
```